# Why does the Azure Devops extension show all code as Not My Code?

Tags: ndepend

When running the NDepend Azure Devops extension for my main build solution, the lines of code show no lines of code for my code and show everything as NotMyCode and I can not determine why.  The JustMyCode Code Elements query from the desktop version indicates hundreds of thousands of elements that are my code.  I'm not sure where to start looking or what could cause this.

Comment: Please come back to us at support at ndepend dot com with screenshots. please check that on the ADO side all assemblies have been resolved properly

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a release build was being generated rather than a debug build, so PDBs were missing.